# graphlab create: unable to start cluster in aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, graphlab

At the moment I'm trying to create a cluster in aws ec2 with Graphlab Create. The code is as follows:

```
import graphlab as gl

ec2config = gl.deploy.Ec2Config(region='us-west-2', instance_type='m3.large',
    aws_access_key_id='secret-acces-key-id', 
    aws_secret_access_key='secret-access-key')

ec2 = gl.deploy.ec2_cluster.create(name='Test Cluster', 
    s3_path='s3://test-big-data-2016', ec2_config=ec2config, idle_shutdown_timeout=3600, num_hosts=1)
```

When the above code is executed I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 59, in 
    ec2 = gl.deploy.ec2_cluster.create(name='Test Cluster', s3_path='s3://test-big-data-2016', ec2_config=ec2config, idle_shutdown_timeout=36000, num_hosts=1)
  File "/Users/remco/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/deploy/ec2_cluster.py", line 83, in create
    cluster.start()
  File "/Users/remco/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/deploy/ec2_cluster.py", line 233, in start
    self.idle_shutdown_timeout
  File "/Users/remco/anaconda/envs/gl-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/deploy/_executionenvironment.py", line 372, in _start_commander_host
    raise RuntimeError('Unable to start host(s). Please terminate '
RuntimeError: Unable to start host(s). Please terminate manually from the AWS console.

When I look in EC2 Management Console a new instance is launched and running. But still getting the error in the terminal.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I followed the exact instructions from: https://turi.com/learn/userguide/deployment/pipeline-example.html